# Parallel.For DateTime

Tags: loops, parallel-processing, async-await

I have loop

```
   List<DateTime> listDate=new List<DateTime>();
    for (DateTime dateTime = startDateTimeGmt; dateTime < endDateTimeGmt; dateTime = dateTime.AddHours(1))
    {                
     listDate.Add(dateTime);
    }
```

I have tried to convert to parallel like some post

```
 var source = Enumerable.Range(0, (endDateTimeGmt - startDateTimeGmt).Hours).Select(t => startDateTimeGmt.AddHours(t));

Parallel.ForEach(source, async dateTime =>
{
listDate.Add(dateTime)
});
```

But it wasn't right.
Could I convert that loop to Parallel ? Somebody can help me.Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var source = Enumerable.Range(0, (endDateTimeGmt - startDateTimeGmt).Hours).Select(t => startDateTimeGmt.AddHours(t));

Parallel.ForEach(source, async dateTime =>
{
listDate.Add(dateTime)
});`enter code here`
```

that my code is correct.Close my topic

Comment: Async is nit needed here

Comment: async dateTime base on your public/private async.If your public/private not async don't use async dateTime like my code.